# kepler glassfish on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-kepler

I've recently installed Kepler Edition on Ubuntu and I'm trying to get my Glassfish 4.0 (open source edition) server runtime set up.

I installed Glassfish separately via the zip file. My directory looks like:

/home/matteo/glassfish4/glassfish
In Eclipse, I installed the jboss tools and the kepler tool. 
I then went into my Preferences | Server | Runtim Environments to add my Glassfish server. When I choose the above path, I get the error message There is no valid GlassFish installlation in the specified directory. I have the Finish button and the Next button locked.

Why?Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be because of the structure of the zip. I had several issues extracting the glassfish-x.zip's containing a subdirectory glassfish which is the Glassfish - instance directory which is expected as the installation directory of glassfish by common IDE's.